# WPF: Static class method updating MainWindow textbox

Tags: wpf, multithreading

How do I update a Control(textbox) present in the MainWindow from a static class's static method in another file?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the main window using a static property of the application class like described here:

```
Application.MainWindow
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx